# Create Deployment Archive From EAR

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I have a multi-module Maven project with an `EAR` and an integration test project. Now I want to have my tests run against some archive that resembles that EAR.

Naturally, my first straight-forward approach was something like that:

```
@Deployment
public static EnterpriseArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(EnterpriseArchive.class,
            "../org.acme.project.ear/target/org.acme.project.ear-1.0.0.ear");
}
```

I figured out how bad an idea that was on my own (for one, I need to build the EAR every time I start a test, and a version number in the code cannot be good either).

So after weeks of work I finally came up with something like this:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "org.acme.project.ear");
    ear.addAsModules(Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("../org.acme.project.ear/pom.xml")
            .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile());
    return ear;
}
```

...which when started doesn't seem to come to an end at all. The entire log is filled with

```
    Jan 04, 2016 9:05:36 AM org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.logging.LogTransferListener transferFailed
    WARNING: Failed downloading org.acme.foo/org.acme.foo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/. Reason: 
    org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could not find metadata org.acme.foo:org.acme.foo/maven-metadata.xml in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
    Jan 04, 2016 9:05:37 AM org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.logging.LogTransferListener transferFailed
    WARNING: Failed downloading org.acme.foo/org.acme.foo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/. Reason: 
    org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could not find metadata org.acme.bar:org.acme.foo/maven-metadata.xml in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

It's no real surprise that if he searches multiple repositories for our company's artifacts he will never come back with a result.

Somewhere along the line I thought maybe it would help to add the artifacts one by one

```
ear.addAsModules(Maven.resolver().resolve("org.acme.foo:org.acme.foo.ejb:ejb:2.0.0").withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class));
```

But this results in the same error message (although less often) and that way I need to define the versions a second time, which is not really what I want.

I found a [a bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SHRINKRES-199?jql=project%20%3D%20SHRINKRES%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC) (that's an April fools' joke, it has to be), but it doesn't help me find what I should do differently to get it to work.

So what is the correct way to assemble an EAR in Arquillian if I already have a Maven EAR project around?